# Trying to convert XML to JSON with %3D and %26 characters

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have the following XML string,

```xml
<xml><row ID="61" url="Page.aspx%3fstepid%3dMyStepID%26ID%3d65454%26UserID%3d2542240%26process%3dMyProcess"></row></xml>
```

I need to convert only the attributes from the URL part of the string to the JSON model.

For example,

```
StepID:MyStepID
ID:65454
UserID:2542240
Process:MyProcess
```

I see that the key and value in the string are separated by `%3D` and all the keys are separated by the character `%26`.

How should I convert this string to JSON?

Comment: Use `Uri.UnescapeDataString` to undo the percentage-encoding, then use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to get a `NameValueCollection`, then pass that to `JsonConvert.Serialize`.

Comment: as it is, neither XML nor JSON care about URL/URI encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can UrlDecode it and get query parameters. ie:

```
void Main()
{
     var urlString = (string)XElement
        .Parse(myxml)
        .Element("row")
        .Attribute("url");
    var query = new Uri("http://myurl/"+HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlString)).Query;
    var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
    
    foreach (var key in parameters.AllKeys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key:{key}, Value:{parameters[key]}");
    }
}

static readonly string myxml = "<xml><row ID=\"61\" url=\"Page.aspx%3fstepid%3dMyStepID%26ID%3d65454%26UserID%3d2542240%26process%3dMyProcess\"></row></xml>";
```

Output:

```
Key:stepid, Value:MyStepID
Key:ID, Value:65454
Key:UserID, Value:2542240
Key:process, Value:MyProcess
```

EDIT: I missed that you want to convert that to JSON. Then you could use Newtonsoft from Nuget:

```
void Main()
{
     var urlString = (string)XElement
        .Parse(myxml)
        .Element("row")
        .Attribute("url");
    var query = new Uri("http://myurl/"+HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlString)).Query;
    var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
    
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var key in parameters.AllKeys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key:{key}, Value:{parameters[key]}");
        dic.Add(key, parameters[key]);
    }
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
}

static readonly string myxml = "<xml><row ID=\"61\" url=\"Page.aspx%3fstepid%3dMyStepID%26ID%3d65454%26UserID%3d2542240%26process%3dMyProcess\"></row></xml>";
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode query string

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    
    var url=  xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("row")[0].Attributes["url"].Value;
    var queryString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
    var index=queryString.IndexOf(".aspx?");
    index=index>0?index+6:0;
    queryString = queryString.Substring(index);
    var pairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    var parameters = (from key in pairs.Cast<string>()
    from value in pairs.GetValues(key)
    select ( key,value)).ToDictionary(p => p.key, p=> p.value);
    
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

json

```
{
  "stepid": "MyStepID",
  "ID": "65454",
  "UserID": "2542240",
  "process": "MyProcess"
}
```